# Only my title shows when using highcharts with php and MySql

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts

I am new to highcharts. I can get the title to show up, but for some reason the x and y axis data won't come up. I am getting my data from a database with php, along with encoding it with JSON. Here is my HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'TCP Upload Speed Averages for Los Angeles County in 2012',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: []
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min:0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'TCP Upload Averages'
                    },
                    labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify'
                }
                },
               legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            }, 

               plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                },
                series: {

                   stacking:'percent' 
                }

            },
                series: []
            };
            $.getJSON("2012Data.php", function(json) {



                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];//xAxis: {categories: []}

                options.series[0] = json[1];



                //chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });

    </script>
    <script src="highstock.js" ></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
```

Here is my JSON data from the php:

[{"name":"Providers","data":["AT&T","Sprint","T-Mobile","Verizon"]},{"name":"Averages","data":[972.03790849673,679.63696969697,992.06606060606,4520.2101851852]}]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does it work without the server side?

Comment: Your chart should be initialised in the ajax callback, like you have commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your chart displays only the title because no data is loaded. And although your AJAX-call might be working: setting the options in its callback is too late, since the callback will most likely be invoked only *after* the chart has been created.

Does it work for you if you uncomment the line `//chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);` in the `getJSON` callback (and of course remove the other Highcharts constructor call two lines down)?

However, the more idiomatic way to load data is to create a callback for the `load`-Event of the chart, fire your AJAX-Request and then insert the data in the already created chart. I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doc_snyder/8rhfpjh6/) for you where i simulate the call to your php-script via a `timeout`. You should get your chart working by using the following load-callback:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function(event) {
      var chart = event.target;

      $.getJSON("2012Data.php", function(json) {
        var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0];
        xAxis.setCategories(json[0]['data']);
        chart.addSeries(json[1]);
      });
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: No, it just shows up blank whenever I have it in the getJSON callback, but I will try this technique

Comment: Everything works out now. Thank you so so much! You don't know how much you helped my teammates and I. I've been stuck on this problem for days.